# PyQt: reset or remove the background color from QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, colors, background, pyqt, qtreewidgetitem

How do I remove the background color of a `QTreeWidgetItem`, or reset it to the default?

```
treeWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor('green'))
```

Comment: How did you set it before?

Comment: treeWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor('green'))  #<-like that ?

Comment: Why would you need to struggle? you would simply do `treeWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor('white'))`

Comment: @ShellRox what if the default background color isn't white?

Comment: @PatrizioBekerle i have mentioned another method below.

Comment: @ShellRox at least in C++ a QTreeWidgetItem doesn't have a `setStyleSheet` method (tested with Qt 5.7)

Answer (score 5):

The correct method is to clear the underlying data, like this:

```python
treeWidgetItem.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, None)
```

---

It's worth noting that when a background has **not** been set, the `background()` method will actually return a *null* `QBrush` rather than `None`. This because the underlying Qt code does this:

```cpp
return qvariant_cast<QBrush>(data(column, Qt::BackgroundRole))
```

So it takes a null `QVariant` (which is equivalent to `None`, in PyQt terms) and casts it to a null `QBrush` - which means it **does not** represent the default system colours, and cannot be used to reset the original values.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is any way of doing it with `setBackgroundColor`, But i would use `setStyleSheet`.

Stylesheet's work with every `QtGui` widget and are more easier to use overall.

If you want to set the `QTreeWidget` **background color** to green:

```
    self.TreeWidgetItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
    self.TreeWidgetItem.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
```

If you want to **reset** the Stylesheet of QTreeWidget, simply type this:

```
    self.TreeWidgetItem.setStyleSheet("")
```

This would reset any widget's color to default one, without giving any exceptions.

Also it is good practice to use qt stylesheet system, It is easy and has a lot of perks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the background colour with this:

```
treeWidgetItem.background(0)
```

returning something like:

```
<PySide.QtGui.QBrush(QColor(ARGB 1, 0, 0, 0) , NoBrush )   at 0x00000000EB1F6588>
```

Now put that into a string before you apply your change and you've got your answer.

```
originalBG = treeWidgetItem.background(0)

# New background
treeWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor('green'))

# Old background
treeWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor(0, originalBG)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value may depend on the OS and other factors.

Since you changed the background color with

```
treeWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor('green'))
```

you can as well read out the default brush before

```
default_tree_widget_item_brush = treeWidgetItem.background(column)
```

and set it back to this later on when you want to return to the default values.

---

Sidenote: In Qt 5.6 there seems to be no method `setBackgroundColor` for `QTreeWidgetItems`, only `setBackground`. So the solution may depend slightly on the used version of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully removed the background color by setting it to a transparent white.

```
treeWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
```

That also works with dark desktop themes.

But since the `setBackgroundColor` method is deprecated I now use:

```
treeWidgetItem.setBackground(0, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 0)))
```